# How can I use method on object which name I have as a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm coming back with another problem.

I have such code:

HTML

```
<button>first</button>
<button>second</button>

<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

JS

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const second = document.querySelector(".second");

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.toggle("pressed");
  let selection = this.textContent;

  // selection.style.transform = "translate(100px)";
}))
```

https://codepen.io/ptr11dev/pen/oREymM

I'd like to create one function that'll be responsible for moving respective div to the right side by 100px - I stuck with such problem. Under "selection" I have respective name of div (stored under the same name), but simple code like

`selection.style.transform = "translate(100px);"`

doesn't work. I know that workaround like creating two functions and using

`first.style.transform = "translate(100px);"`

and

`second.style.transform = "translate(100px);"`

would work, but in my main code it's a bit more complicated.

I'll really appreciate any input from your side. Thanks

P.S. I'd like to use Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them by the class name, assuming that the button text and their class are the same.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const second = document.querySelector(".second");

btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.toggle("pressed");
  let selection = this.textContent;
  
  document.querySelector(`.${selection}`).style.transform = "translate(100px)";
}))
```

```css
div{
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button>first</button>
<button>second</button>

<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is textContext is just that TEXT not an object. This sets selection as the first element that matches the class name pulled as this.textContent;

```
let selection = document.getElementsByClassName(this.textContent)[0];
selection.style.transform = "translate(100px)";
```

Comment: Hmm.. That would work but it means I have two references to the same object.

Comment: @PiotrKaczmarek, if you aren't using `first` and `second` then you don't need to declare them. My answer just like the other answer does the same thing in two different methods. You can rig something up using `eval` or some weird array, but you are then overcomplicating things just so you can reuse the variables that you already declared,

Comment: Yea, I've rewrote my project so that worked. Thank you very much!